# `scan': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby, regex, file, utf-8

I'm trying to read a `.txt` file in ruby and split the text line-by-line.

Here is my code:

```
def file_read(filename)
  File.open(filename, 'r').read
end

puts f = file_read('alice_in_wonderland.txt')
```

This **works perfectly**. But when I add the method `line_cutter` like this:

```
def file_read(filename)
  File.open(filename, 'r').read
end

def line_cutter(file)
  file.scan(/\w/)
end

puts f = line_cutter(file_read('alice_in_wonderland.txt'))
```

I get an error:

```
`scan': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
```

I found [this](http://po-ru.com/diary/fixing-invalid-utf-8-in-ruby-revisited/) online for untrusted website and tried to use it for my own code but it's not working. How can I remove this error?

Link to the file: [File](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/vip/teach/Algorithms/7_hash_RBtree_simpleDS/hw_hash_RBtree/alice_in_wonderland.txt)

Comment: @sawa Sorry, I wanted to know how to remove this error.

Comment: The linked article was written in 2006, you are not using Ruby 1.8, are you?

Comment: @Stefan no I'm using 2.2.1. Thanks

Comment: It is better to do `File.read(filename)`. That won't mess with the file kept open.

Comment: @sawa done. I'm still getting the same error though.

Comment: You could post the file or the part that causes this error?

Comment: @sawa updated my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The linked text file contains the following line:

> Character set encoding: ISO-8859-1

If converting it isn't desired or possible then you have to tell Ruby that this file is [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) encoded. Otherwise the [default external encoding](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Encoding.html#method-c-default_external) is used ([UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) in your case). A possible way to do that is:

```
s = File.read('alice_in_wonderland.txt', encoding: 'ISO-8859-1')
s.encoding  # => #<Encoding:ISO-8859-1>
```

Or even like this if you prefer your string UTF-8 encoded (see [utf8everywhere.org](http://utf8everywhere.org/)):

```
s = File.read('alice_in_wonderland.txt', encoding: 'ISO-8859-1:UTF-8')
s.encoding  # => #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems to work if you read the file directly from the page, maybe there's something funny about the local copy you have.  Try this:

```
require 'net/http'

uri = 'http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/vip/teach/Algorithms/7_hash_RBtree_simpleDS/hw_hash_RBtree/alice_in_wonderland.txt'
scanned = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(uri)).body.scan(/\w/)
```